# Is it possible to authenticate WITHOUT Facebook installing an app?

Tags: authentication, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-app-requests, facebook-authorization

I'm building a public voting system for a company's event. Facebook auth would be a feasible way of implementation.
The problem is that the client specifically doesn't want an application to be installed in the voters profile. Is there a way to authenticate a user without the application being installed or is installing the app generally the core of the process?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In order to retrieve information about the user (like user_id, email, etc.), they must authenticate with your app.

Keep in mind that although it works in the same manner, you can have users "log in" to your app with their facebook account, but not post anything, nor request any special permissions, etc. Kind of a change in perspective there. Make the default privacy on your app for each user "only me", and then it definitely won't show up anywhere.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I'm afraid the client wants no application to be installed on behalf on FB so I guess even with the app's permissions set to "only me" this way of doing things will not be good enough.